# using jquery fadein to display a selection of links on page load

Tags: jquery, css, fading

I want to use jQuery to fade in links inside a nav div on page load. Currently they're styled using an `a` and have individual id's.

```
#navtop a {etc.}
```

Will I have to change that into a class, add another one that hides the links and reapply the the class when the fadein starts or is there an easier method?

Also I'd like the links to fade in one after another.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="navtop">
    <a id="link1" href="link.php"><img src="img/logotrans.gif" width="30" height="30" /></a>
    <a id="link2" href="link.php">News</a>
    <a id="link3" href="link.php">Blog</a>
    <a id="link4" href="link.php">Tour</a>
    <a id="link5" href="link.php">Photos</a>
    <a id="link6" href="link.php">About</a>
    <a id="link7" href="link.php">Contact</a>
 </div>
```

This is as far as I've got with the JavaScript:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#link1').fadeIn(5000, function() {
        // Animation complete
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please include an example of the HTML you currently have and any applicable JavaScript?

Comment: @ghayes added the html and java

Comment: @frank .... Java and Javascript are the same... right? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can queue up the fade-ins with a [jQuery queue](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=queue).  Like so:

[**See it live at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/24CXZ/2/)

```
//--- Queue-up the fade-in's
var animationQ = $({});

$("#navtop a").each ( function () {
    var jThis = $(this);

    animationQ.queue ('FadeIns', function (nextQ_Item) {

        jThis.fadeIn (5000, function() {
            nextQ_Item ();
        } );
    } );
} );

//--- Start the fade-ins.
animationQ.dequeue ('FadeIns');
```

This approach has the advantage that you can queue up any collection of nodes, just by changing the selector.  They do not have to be siblings.

---

**Update:**
To stagger the fade-in starts part-way in, use:

```
var fadeTime    = 5000; //-- How long will an individual fade last? (mS)
var fadeStagger = 500;  /*-- How far into i=one element's fade will 
                             the next elements fade start? (mS)
                        */

//--- Queue-up the fade-in's
var animationQ = $({});

$("#navtop a").each ( function (J) {
    var jThis = $(this);

    animationQ.queue ('FadeIns', function (nextQ_Item) {
        jThis.fadeTo (fadeStagger, fadeStagger / fadeTime , function() {
            nextQ_Item ();
            jThis.fadeTo (fadeTime - fadeStagger, 1);
        } );
    } );
} );

//--- Start the fade-ins.
animationQ.dequeue ('FadeIns');
```

[**See it at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/24CXZ/3/)

---

**Requested explanation:**

1. We set up a generic queue container by jQuery-ing on an empty object ( `$({})` ).  This seems cleaner than attaching the queue to some node.
2. We select our nodes with any valid jQuery selector, and then use [the `each()` function<sup>Doc</sup>](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=each) to loop through them.
3. For each node, we add an entry into our custom queue, using [the `queue()` function<sup>Doc</sup>](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=queue).

   1. We give the queue a unique name, "FadeIns," to avoid conflicts.
   2. Each queue entry will passed a pointer to the next queue entry, when it's called.  We capture that with the `nextQ_Item` variable.
   3. The queue item, function has 2 jobs: (1) do the item fade, and (2) call the next queue entry when it is done.
   4. However, we have split the [fade<sup>Doc</sup>](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=fadeTo) into 2 parts to accomplish the desired staggered-start.

      1. The first fade lasts only for the `fadeStagger` delay time.  We calculate the ending opacity by the ratio of the delay time to the overall time.
      2. Now we trigger the next element.
      3. Next, we resume and complete the fade, remembering that it only has (total - stagger-delay) milliseconds left.
4. Once our custom queue is built, we fire it off with [the `dequeue()` function<sup>Doc</sup>](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=dequeue).

Comment: thanks, would it possible to have the next node start fading before the previous one has finished eg 500 ms into the animation

Comment: Hi , could you give a brief explanation of the code . I don't want to get into the habbit of asking questions instead of learning .

Comment: Okay, I explained the code as best I could.  That was work!  Next time I'm answering with "PFM" ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to change any of your markup. What you want can be achieved easily with the code below. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/pJ5uC/

```
$(window).load(function () {
    fadeA($('#navtop a:first-child'));
});

function fadeA(elem) {
    elem.fadeIn(500, function () {
        fadeA($(this).next());
    });
}
```

I've used 500 rather than 5000 to speed up the viewing process.

Comment: thanks , in the live example the navtop css has display none . if i want to keep the current styling will i have to change it into a class? link to the site : [link](http://www.francisastindesigns.com/techielunchbox)

Comment: @frank: No need to change anything to a class, just add `display:none` into the current `#navtop a` css rule. You cannot `fadeIn` the links if they are not hidden to begin with.

Comment: would it possible to have the next child start fading before the previous one has finished eg 500 ms into the animation.

Answer (score 0):

This will get them to all fadein at the same time.

```
$('#navtop a').fadeIn('slow', function() {
   // Animation complete
});
```

You will need to set up some sort of setTimeout and loop over them